# What event is called when opening the app after pressing home button

Tags: android, events, android-studio

I am using the app and i press homebutton , than i open it from launch icon, but no event gets fired, i have override onresume and manyothers , which is the right event?

Comment: Please show some code, because if the app retruns to the foreground, onResume should be invoked.

Comment: It kind of depends. Usually `onStart()`, then `onResume()`. You can see the conditions under which each is run on the documentation site. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Well if i press home button, and open the launch icon , none of those events are beign fired i think, what code do you need?

Comment: I agree with @Udi. You should be able to use logcat to find out what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    this.finish();

    return true;

 }
```

Use this code: It works me . 
http://www.lifecracked.com/home-button-on-actionbar-or-toolbar-in-android/